# Find root category of store

Tags: magento

I am using Magento ver1.6.1. I need to get the root category of a store. I search in google by didn't get any good idea/code. Let me know how to get the root category of a store?

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()
```

The above code gives the default root category, but I need the category Id which we select during store creation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

have you tried:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
```

Comment: Note that if you are fetching store data within an install/upgrade script for an extension, you must run Mage::init() first, or the store object will not be populated.

Answer (score 0):

Writing it for my own help as my platform was configured in multi store views and by all means I was not getting the correct root category id. I all of the below solutions:

Sol 1:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId(); //The result was ID: 2
```

Sol 2:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId(); //The result was ID: 2
```

Sol 3:

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::DISTRO_STORE_ID);
$categoryId = $store->getRootCategoryId();// The result was again ID: 2
```

The method that only worked and returned `ID: 1` is given below and was taken from [here](http://scriptbaker.com/get-magento-root-category-id/)

```
public function getRootCategoryId()
{
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $categIds = $categories->getAllIds();
    asort($categIds);
    foreach ($categIds as $k => $catId)
    {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
        if ($category->name)
        {
            return $catId;
        }
    }
}
```