# Magento: How to get the root category id for a specific store in an upgrade script?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

How do I get the root category in a Magento 1.9 update script?

[Find root category of store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700976/find-root-category-of-store) proposes a solution, but I get an error message after running the script:

```
Mage registry key "controller" already exists
```

... as well as a trace:

```
#0 /var/www/instances/global/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/instances/global/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(762): Mage::register('controller', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front))
#2 /var/www/instances/global/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1113): Mage_Core_Model_App-&gt;_initFrontController()
#3 /var/www/instances/global/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_App-&gt;getFrontController()
#4 /var/www/instances/global/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front-&gt;_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/instances/global/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front-&gt;dispatch()
#6 /var/www/instances/global/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App-&gt;run(Array)
#7 /var/www/instances/global/index.php(118): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

My script calls the Mage::init first, then tries to read the root category name of the store.

```
Mage::init();
Mage::app()->getStore(3)->getRootCategoryId();
```

The error message seems to be quite common; [Mage registry key "controller" already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737069/mage-registry-key-controller-already-exists) indicates Mage::run might have been run twice.

I therefore assume that Mage::init also should not be called twice, and is maybe invoked again after my update script is invoked - and this could cause my error message. All assumptions.

What could i do? Omit Mage::init()? But then, I do not get the root id. Destroy the object(s) created by Mage::init()? How?

Comment: This would be better suited for the Magento SE site.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I did not know it exists. Next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not elegant, but does not need a Mage::init() call and can therefore invoked in a Magento upgrade script:

```
$myStoreId = 4;
$myStoresRootCategoryId = null;
foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
    $storeId = $store->getId();
    $rootCategoryId = $store->getGroup()->getRootCategoryId();
    if ($storeId == $myStoreId) {
        $myStoresRootCategoryId = $rootCategoryId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have many types to access root category id.

1- `Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();`

2- `Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();`

3-

```
 $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::DISTRO_STORE_ID);
        $categoryId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I tried these already:

1 - does not work without Mage::init(), always returns the same root category id for all stores

2 - returns the root category for the currently selected store, but not for a specific one

3 - same as 1

Comment: How can i get selected store id products, my code https://justpaste.it/6fi1f, when i use this code it is display all my products, how can i add filter  for selected store products lists.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Mage::init();` nor `Mage::run();` in upgrade scripts (installers)!

You can still get the root id after omitting `Mage::init();`

Comment: If I do not use Mage::init(), the code returns the same root category id for all stores in the system.